# Is it possible to label all files using git

Tags: c#, git

Is there a  way to tag/label/... all files in a git repository?

Some background:

We create a branch per release version. Our master is our development version. Bug fixes are done on our master and then cherry picked to the correct 'version' branch(es).

This all works well. However, we are losing track of **when** changes are made.
In our 'old' system, we could label all our files prior to a version closure. So we always knew which version a change was made.

Example:

- version 5
- version 4
- some change
- version 3
- initial creation of file

Now, in git, we only see 'initial creation' and 'some change', but we can't easily see in which version this happened.

Is there a way to label the files (or commits) so we can see which version something was changed?
What is best practice to do this?

Comment: What do you mean you're losing track of when changes are made?  Each commit has a timestamp, right?

Comment: isn't this `git tag` ?

Comment: We have the timestamps, but then we have to go check when the version was closed. This isn't the way to go in a mostly automated world.

Comment: It seems that you are coming from TFVC. A commit, is already kind of a snapshot of all the files. So, you only have to tag a commit to do a label of all the files at a specific state.

Answer (score 0):

Within git you don't label your files with a "last change" timestamp. Commits themselves have timestamps which allow for such information to be reconstructed upon need.

Do you want to know when file `path/to/file` has changed for the last time ?

```
git log --all -1 -- path/to/file
```

...will output the last commit which changed the file, with author and date.

But if you have version tags in your repo tree and want to have this info about your file, you might prefer to pass the commit hash to `describe` :

```
git describe `git log --all -1 --pretty=format:"%H" -- path/to/file`
```

Comment: Is there a way to visualise this in the Visual Studio History? We've recently converted from an older language to c# and most of my colleagues are still learning the language and VS. Going command line with git would most likely be too much to handle right now.

Comment: I don't know VS interface myself, I'll let others answer, but I would be very surprised if it were not possible. It's a very common need with source control.